# Postfix - unable to send mails to Internet (i.e. Gmail)

Tags: debian, email, postfix

I've set up postfix (Debian) and it works fine. I can recieve mail and I can send them, but I can only send them to local (and local virtual) adresses.

But when I try to send the mail for example to my Gmail account, I get this in syslog:

```
Jun 30 18:34:44 vps postfix/smtpd[9087]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from vps[77.93.223.122]: 554 5.7.1 <hrdina.pavel@gmail.com>: Relay access denied; from=<info@w-cms.cz> to=<hrdina.pavel@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<localhost.localdomain>
```

I've googled a lot but I did figure it out thought. I think that something is wrong with my* directives. Here are mine:

```
myhostname = mail.xxx.cz
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = xxx.cz, vps, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
```

Comment: Isn't your hostname `w-cms.cz`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allow relaying for hosts you trust.

If `vps` has a static IP address, you might simply add it to `mynetworks`. Another popular option is to set up authentication between trusted hosts

See furthermore http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html